# QGIS plugin testing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have written a few QGIS plugins and would like to set up some test suites. I have one plugin that has no UI and standard unittest works. But on my plugins with UI, initiated using the plugin builder plugin, loading the plugin throws an ImportError

```
   from .resources import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How do I get around this? My structure is, eg for the Spectral data loader plugin

```
qgisspectrereader/
  - DataLoader.py
  - resources.py
  - __init__.py
  - tests/
       - test_loader.py
```

Where test_loader.py starts with

```
 import unittest
 from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsPointXY, QgsCoordinateTransform
 from DataLoader import DataLoader
```

And the error is thrown on the third line.

(I know this is a quite general python question, but when looking for help I have only found solutions that would not be appliciable to a QGIS plugin. I would guess somebody here has written unittests for plugins with an UI)